# How to improve text quality in Flash with enabled 3D?

Tags: flash, text, 3d

I've put text in TextField, set Z coordinate to enable 3D, and placed object close to the screen plane. Text quality is very bad. Is there any way to force Flash draw proper vector text? Fonts are embedded, so it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may have already tried this, but if not, try calling the following on your TextField object:

```
myTextField.antiAliasType = flash.text.AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
```